# PHP Login Script Causing Blank Page

Tags: php, html, css, sql, apache

So I'm working on a PHP/SQL login script for my website.  The server is a UNIX system running Apache, and PHP is installed, that much I know for sure.  I have the SQL database set up, and I have my PHP code divided into sections.

http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/membership.php';
    $membership = new Membership()

    if($_POST && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
        $response = $membership->validate_User($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Woodland Astronomy Club Website">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Woodland, Astronomy, Club, Website, Moss, Lake, Neighborhood, Astronomical, Association">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="wasmain.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
        <title>Woodland Astronomy Club - Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="IMG_9897 2 (3) copy.jpg" alt="we has a issue, sorrys!1!!!" width="100%" height="200px">
                <div id="linkbar">
                    <p class="linkbarbutton">
                        <b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/index.html">Home</a></b>
                    </p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/aboutus.html">About Us</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/events.html">Club Events</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/eventpix.html">Club Photos</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/astropix.html">Astrophotography</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.weatherlink.com/user/theweathercat/" target="_blank">Weather Station</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/contact.html">Contact Us</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/links.html">External Links</a></b></p>
                    <p class="linkbarbutton"><b><a class="linkbarlink" href="http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/members.html">Members</a></b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="fluffy"></div>
                <div id="login">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <h2 class="yellowlabel">Login <small>Enter Your Credentials</small></h2>
                        <p class="yellowlabel">
                            <label for="username" >Username: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="username">
                        </p>
                        <p class="yellowlabel">
                            <label for="password">Password: </label>
                            <input type="password" name="pwd">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
                        </p>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($response)) echo "<h4 class='alert'>" . $response . "</h4>";
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

then,

http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/membership.php:

```
<?php
    require 'http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/Mysql.php';

    class Membership {
        function validate_user($un, $pwd) {
            $mysql = New Mysql();
            $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

            if($ensure_credentials) {
                $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
                header("location: http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/members.html");
            } else return "Please enter a correct username and password";
        }
    }
?>
```

then,

http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/mysql.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/constants.php';

    class Mysql {
        private $conn;

        function __construct() {
            $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
            die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
        }

        function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {

            $query = "SELECT *
                      FROM Membership
                      WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
                      LIMIT 1";

            if($stmt = this->conn->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $stmt->close();
                    return true;        
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

and lastly,

http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/constants.php:

```
 <?php
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', '/*I didn't want to put my database credentials on the web, you understand...');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'Member');
?>
```

So before, the page was entirely blank, but that was syntax errors in the include files.  After I found this, I started getting error messages telling me that PHP couldn't connect to the MySQL database.  After some more work, I managed to get rid of error messages altogether, but now when I click Login, it simply tries to load until the browser eventually gives the message "The connection to the server was reset."

I'm lost.  My neighbor is good with PHP, but he's out of town since this afternoon, and I can't seem to figure this one out on my own.

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

Sorry for the exceedingly long question.

Thanks, Harold

Comment: Have you tried replacing the file you navigate to (login.php?) with very simple test commands (e.g. `this is text outside php <?php echo ' and this is inside php'; ?>`) to see if it gets printed?

Comment: Do **not** `require_once` over http if you can avoid it. If it is a local file, treat it as a local file (and probably `allow_url_include` is _disabled_ for this very good reason, leave that setting as it is).

Comment: Also, activating full error reporting is always a good idea: add `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of the first file that gets executed.

Comment: What is this? if($_POST && .....

Comment: @WigglerJtag - Not sure, my neighbor and I were working on this earlier this afternoon and that was his code, not mine.  He's gone now, so I'm on my own for a few days.

Comment: Also, I turned on error reporting, and it told me that http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/membership.php doesn't exist, but I've chedcked and it does.  Any ideas on what that's all about?

Comment: Maybe it does but you point it to wrong folder.. You have to learn debugging and finding bugs, it told you where the problem is and you have to find it...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using XDebug and/or turning on some error tracking.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Okay, tried that, and what I ended up with is an error telling me that woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/membership.php doesn't exist, but I've checked and it does. Any idea what that means?

Comment: I would check the permissions of the file. Make sure that it can be read by Apache.

Comment: Okay, I looked at that for a bit, and it was me referencing the file wrong.  Typical.  So I've actually got the page loading, and what I've run into is an error that I think is saying the page can't connect to the SQL database.  When I click "Login", the top of the page loads the characters: 
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46) in /cgi-bin/classes/mysql.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /cgi-bin/classes/mysql.php on line 20

Comment: Check out the my.cnf file to make sure the mysql.sock path is right.

Answer (score 0):

Do you turn on error reporting?
Il will show the PHP error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Comment: Okay, tried that, and what I ended up with is an error telling me that http://www.woodlandastronomy.org/cgi-bin/classes/membership.php doesn't exist, but I've checked and it does.  Any idea what that means?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve error on terminal. For example, your site is localhost/yourproject

1. Open Terminal (Ctl+ Alt + T)
2. `cd /var/log/apache2`
3. You can see error.log in this folder
4. `tail -f error.log`
5. Run again your site and checks log at terminal

If you specific error log with domain name, e.g error-woodlandastronom.log,
check like that `tail -f error-woodlandastronom.log`

Ps. You can also truck access.log like that `tail -f access.log`

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you are using SQL server for database.

Therefore, you can not use mysql functions. $mysql = New Mysql();

You can use mssql functions for php.

Make sure your extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll extension should be on.

You can easily check it by printing

If not, open php.ini and remove ';' from infront of ;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll and restart the server.